# How to parse variables in Ansible group_vars dictionary?

Tags: variables, dictionary, ansible, inventory

I have previously been placing all of my variables within the inventory file, such as

```
dse_dir=/app/dse
dse_bin_dir={{ dse_dir }}/bin
dse_conf_dir={{ dse_dir }}/resources/dse/conf
dse_yaml_loc={{ dse_conf_dir }}/dse.yaml
cass_conf_dir={{ dse_dir }}/resources/cassandra/conf
cass_yaml_loc={{ cass_conf_dir }}/cassandra.yaml
cass_bin_dir={{ dse_dir }}/resources/cassandra/bin
```

I did not need to use any quotes for these variables in the inventory file and it worked quite well.

Now I am trying to make use of the group_vars functionality, to separate variables per group of hosts. This has a different format, being a dictionary. So now I have:

```
dse_dir: "/app/dse"
dse_bin_dir: "{{ dse_dir }}/bin"
dse_conf_dir: "{{ dse_dir }}/resources/dse/conf"
dse_yaml_loc: "{{ dse_conf_dir }}/dse.yaml"
cass_conf_dir: "{{ dse_dir }}/resources/cassandra/conf"
cass_yaml_loc: "{{ cass_conf_dir }}/cassandra.yaml"
cass_bin_dir: "{{ dse_dir }}/resources/cassandra/bin"
```

In order to avoid parsing complains, I need to place quotes around these parameters. But now when I have a playbook such as the following:

```
---
# Copy CQL files across
- include: subtasks/copy_scripts.yml

- name: Create users
  command: '{{ cass_bin_dir })/cqlsh'
```

I get the following error. Omitting the single quotes or replacing them with double quotes does not work either.

```
ERROR: There was an error while parsing the task 'command {{ cass_bin_dir })/cqlsh'.
Make sure quotes are matched or escaped properly
```

All of the documentation that I could find only shows hardcoded values in the dictionary, i.e. without variables including other variables, but I would assume that Ansible would support this.

Any advice on how to parse these properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the “Gotchas” section [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/YAMLSyntax.html) for understanding why you needed to add the quotes in your `group_vars`. (It's the yaml/ansible problematic `: {{` combo.)

To address the error in your `command`, fix the typo: you have a `})` instead of `}}`.